# Redis: Publish pipelined/batched messages - Get pipelined/batched messages

Tags: redis, publish-subscribe, redisson

I'm using redisson as a java redis client.

When I send a batch with multiple .publish(msg) commands to redis,
does redis send these messages as a "batch/pipeline" back to the subscribers
in ONE network connection so that redisson handles them all at once?

Regards, RoboFlax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mrniko, a worker on redisson, answered with no.
https://github.com/redisson/redisson/issues/1347#issuecomment-374651601